# How do I set sound output to mono?

Tags: sound

Because I live in a house with other people, I need to listen to music with headphones on. However, the left earphone unexpectedly stopped working (whilst the right still works perfectly). How do I set the output to mono so that I can properly listen to music?

EDIT: I know only the right earphone will work, but I still only hear part of the music (the part that would have normally gone only to the left earphone doesn't go to the right, even if the left is broken).

Comment: Ummm, if your left earphone is broken, how will that help you? You will still hear only with your right ear...

Comment: I laughed out loud! Breaking one earphone is the quickest way to set the output to mono.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can I downmix stereo audio to mono?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/17791/can-i-downmix-stereo-audio-to-mono)

Answer (score 7):

I have the same situation...
found a solution [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/17791/can-i-downmix-stereo-audio-to-mono)

p.s. I know 2 years have passed, just not to leave the question unanswered