# Enable Mono Audio output in Ubuntu 22.04lts

Tags: pulseaudio, alsa, 22.04, mono, pipewire

I would like to enable mono audio output through my earphone;this was possible previously in ubuntu 20.04(vanilla) with these instructions: [Can I downmix stereo audio to mono?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/17791/can-i-downmix-stereo-audio-to-mono/99960#99960)
However,it doesn't seem to work anymore with ubuntu 22.04.I suspect it might be due to pipewire,but I don't know exactly what to do about it.Any help would be appreciated.Thanks.

Comment: I had the same problem, this is the solution I found: https://askubuntu.com/a/1441611