# How can I downmix stereo audio output to mono in PipeWire (on 22.10)?

Tags: drivers, sound, pulseaudio, alsa, pipewire

I need a way to set **mono audio output** on my system.
I had used this solution before: [Can I downmix stereo audio to mono?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/17791/can-i-downmix-stereo-audio-to-mono)

```sh
pacmd load-module module-remap-sink sink_name=mono master=NAME_OF_AUDIO_SINK \
 channels=2 channel_map=mono,mono
```

However, it stopped working when I upgraded to Kubuntu 22.10, presumably because it now uses PipeWire instead of PulseAudio. When I do `pacmd list-sinks` I get:
`No PulseAudio daemon running, or not running as session daemon.`

How can I do the same (downmix stereo audio output to mono) on PipeWire?

I found [here](https://blogshit.baka.fi/2021/07/pipewire-microphone/) a solution to a similar problem, but if I understand correctly that's for getting mono *input*. I want mono *output*.
Even better if I can easily switch it to mono/stereo using GUI, or set it to mono only when my stupid earphones are connected.

PS: They should really implement Mono Sound as a profile/configuration on System Settings > Audio, but oh well...

Comment: Also asked here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1409194/enable-mono-audio-output-in-ubuntu-22-04lts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to make mono audio output work in PipeWire by installing [EasyEffects](https://github.com/wwmm/easyeffects) equalizer.

```sh
sudo apt install easyeffects
```

1. Output > Effects > Add Effect > Stereo Tools
2. On Stereo Matrix tab, choose "Mono Sum L+R". "Stereo to Mid-Side" seems to work too.
3. In Preferences, make sure to enable "Launch Service at System Startup".
4. Create presets for "Mono" and "Stereo" if desired (optional).

[image: EasyEffects - Downmix audio output to mono]
[image: EasyEffects - Launch service at system startup]

Comment: Thanks. This works in my Fedora distro too.

Answer (score 2):

I managed to achieve true mono output by combining the stereo stream into a mono sink [Pipewire - Module Combine Stream](https://docs.pipewire.org/page_module_combine_stream.html):

use `$ wpctl status` to get the sink id of your desired sink and `$ wpctl inspect [ID]` to get the node.name variable to use on the configuration file.

```
$ wpctl status

PipeWire 'pipewire-0' [0.3.56, user@hostname, cookie:1163266174]

Audio
 ├─ Devices:
 │      42. HD Audio Controller                 [alsa]
 │     105. USB PnP Audio Device                [alsa]
 │
 ├─ Sinks:
 │  *   48. HD Audio Controller Analog Stereo   [vol: 0.50]
 │
 ├─ ...
 │
 ├─ Sources:
 │  *  101. USB PnP Audio Device Mono           [vol: 0.74]
 │
 └─ ...
```

```
$ wpctl inspect 48

id 48, type PipeWire:Interface:Node
    ...
    ...
  * factory.id = "18"
    factory.mode = "merge"
    factory.name = "api.alsa.pcm.sink"
    ...
  * media.class = "Audio/Sink"
  * node.description = "HD Audio Controller Analog Stereo"
  * node.name = "alsa_output.pci-0000_08_00.4.analog-stereo"
  * node.nick = "ALC1220 Analog"
    ...
  * object.path = "alsa:pcm:1:front:1:playback"
  * object.serial = "49"
    ...
```

- In your distribution folder of pipewire(usually `/usr/share/pipewire`), find the `pipewire.conf` file and add this configuration with the modifications that suits your needs. You can either just copy the part inside `context.modules=[]` or create a new file and add to the `~/.config/pipewire/pipewire.conf.d/` or `~/.config/pipewire/pipewire-pulse.conf.d` directories.
- At the `context.modules` section:

```
context.modules = [
{   name = libpipewire-module-combine-stream
        args = {
            combine.mode = sink
            node.name = "combine_stereo_to_mono_sink" # Can be any name of your choice
            node.description = "Mono Speakers" # This is the name that will appear in the sound settings
            combine.latency-compensate = false
            combine.props = {
            audio.position = [ MONO ]
            }
            stream.props = {
                stream.dont-remix = true
            }
            stream.rules = [
            {   matches = [
                    {   media.class = "Audio/Sink"
                        node.name = "alsa_output.pci-0000_08_00.4.analog-stereo" # Your node.name here
                    } ]
                    actions = { create-stream = {
                            audio.position = [ FL FR ]
                            combine.audio.position = [ MONO ] # These both are what combine both channels into one
                    } } }
            ]
        }
    }
]
```

After saving the file, either reboot your system or restart pipewire and wireplumber:

`$ systemctl --user restart pipewire pipewire-pulse wireplumber`

This is my sound settings:
[Mono Speakers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JvoMP.png)
[Mono Speakers2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KLouJ.png)

Comment: This doesn't work for me on Kubuntu 23.10. Instead, it makes all audio settings disappear. I made sure to use the correct node.name from `wpctl inspect`.

Comment: I'll try on a VM with Kubuntu to check the possible errors @emk2203, here on both fedora 39 and ubuntu 23.04 it worked, but both are gnome

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you could use [qpwgraph](https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/rncbc/qpwgraph) and link both L and R channels in a manner similar to this:

[image]

Profiles can be saved, but for that I redirect you to the docs. Here is a bit about saving and loading profiles with pipewire on ArchWiki: https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/PipeWire#PipeWire_patch_sets_for_command_line

Comment: OK, so I tried this. While this connection in the answer is wrong (it's linking mic to output), I was able to make it work *temporarily* for my case by linking `monitor_FL` to `playback_FR` (my earphone problem is that it has only R output on both sides, so although this isn't "mono" it would work for me; mixing connections didn't work). HOWEVER I was not able to persist settings across reboots. The program is probably buggy, because I couldn't make it apply the profile on startup via command-line - I would have to manually make the connection every time, which doesn't solve my problem.

Comment: I tried many different things, but the app doesn't even load the connection in the saved profile correctly.

Comment: @Tooster I have to say; even if this wouldn't work (that is if it won't work), I must say this anyway, a nice program recommendation!  +1 for that, really.

Answer (score 1):

- Another solution without the need to install another program would be creating a mono output configuration file for PipeWire.
- For example the following configuration can be done per user session:

  - Create a `mono-playback.conf` in `~/.config/pipewire/pipewire.conf.d` with the following:

    ```
    context.modules = [
        { name = libpipewire-module-loopback
            args = {
                node.description = "Mono Playback Device"
                capture.props = {
                    node.name      = "mono_output"
                    media.class    = "Audio/Sink"
                    audio.position = [ MONO ]
                }
                playback.props = {
                    node.name      = "playback.mono_output"
                    audio.position = [ MONO ]
                    node.passive   = true
                }
            }
        }
    ]
    ```
  - Restart pipewire service:

    ```
    systemctl --user restart pipewire{,-pulse}.{service,socket}
    ```
  - This will create a virtual device (a sink in this case) named `Mono Playback Device`
  - The device can be selected by GUI from an audio applet or system settings. [Example using KDE Plasma audio applet.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZNadC.png)
- For Further reading to understand the options you can refer to [PipeWire  Wiki](https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/pipewire/pipewire/-/wikis/home), [Virtual Devices](https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/pipewire/pipewire/-/wikis/Virtual-Devices) section.

Comment: Good, easy, device-independent solution. The volume seems to depend on the volume of the stereo volume settings, if set to 80%, it's about equal to it.